# Filter an array by value

Tags: freemarker, mvel

Say I have an unordered array called `users`:

```
"users": [
   {"id": "6", "name": "Bob"},
   {"id": "2", "name": "Ryan"}
]
```

Is there any way to get the user with `id == 2` inside my MVEL (or Freemarker) template?  If none or multiple, then throw error.  It seems possible with `@foreach`, but I would prefer more concise.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker has not built-in functionality for this (it has for `{"6": "Bob", "2": "Ryan"}`), so you have to write a `#function` for this.

```
<#function getById(idNamePairs, id)>
  <#local found = false>
  <#list idNamePairs as idNamePair>
    <#if idNamePair.id == id>
      <#if found>
        <#stop "Id not unique: ${id}">
      </#if>
      <#local name = idNamePair.name>
      <#local found = true>
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <#if !found>
    <#stop "No entry with this id: ${id}">
  </#if>
  <#return name>
</#function>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
${getById(users, "6")}
```